# Session not being saved as id

Tags: php, mysql

basically I have been pulling my hair out over an unknown problem with my PHP code.

CODE(`login_config.php`):

```
    <?php   
session_start();                    //POST VARIABLES
                        $submit = $_POST['login_submit'];
                        $password = $_POST['login_password'];
                        $email = $_POST['login_email'];



if(isset($submit)){
   require 'password_config.php';
   require 'connect.php';

//PASSWORD VERIFYING
   $pass_query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
   $queried = mysql_query($pass_query);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queried)){
   $user_pass = $row['password'];
   $veri_password = password_verify($password, $user_pass);
   }
   if($veri_password != true){$errors[] = '-Account does not exist ';}
   elseif($veri_password = true){

//CHECKING NUM ROWS
   $sql = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
   $entered_user = mysql_query($sql);
   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($entered_user);
   //STORING ID AS SESSION
   while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($entered_user)){
   //PROBLEM IS HERE 
   $row1['id'] = $id;
   }

//ERRS ARRAY ESTABLISHED
   $errors = array();

//FURTHER VERIFYING
   if( empty($password) || empty($email) )
   {
   $errors[] = 'Please do not leave fields empty';
   }
   elseif( $num_rows != 1 )
   {
   $errors[] = '-Account does not exist ';
   }
   elseif( $num_rows == 1 )
   {
   $id = $_SESSION['key'];

      header('Location: profile.php');
      exit();
      }
   }

   }
?>
```

Question: Why is it that, when I get redirected to profile.php via header(), $_SESSION['key'] value is null? I have been using var_dump() to prove this. I want my session key to have a value of the user's id in my database and I see no problems with my code.

Comment: first thing you are using while loop to fetch password, how many passwords you wana fetch, really bad approach

Comment: 2nd you are again running loop and trying to load `id` into `$id` not possible at all

Comment: Why cant I store the id column value in the variable $id?

Comment: please check my answer below and in PHP code i commented infront of code where you are making mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `$id` variable is **not defined** anywhere.

Doing `$row1['id'] = $id;` means `assigning $id value to $row1['id']`
If you want to store user id in `$id` then you should use

```
$id = $row1['id'];
```

The same bug with `$id = $_SESSION['key'];` This means `assiging $_SESSION['key'] to $id`. If you want to store `$id` value in a session:

```
$_SESSION['key'] = $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code as far i can see, both are you are running loop to fetch data so here is the code and i marked the lines where you are doing wring

```
<?php   
session_start(); 
//POST VARIABLES
$submit = $_POST['login_submit'];
$password = $_POST['login_password'];
$email = $_POST['login_email'];

if(isset($submit)){
   require 'password_config.php';
   require 'connect.php';

//PASSWORD VERIFYING
   $pass_query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
   $queried = mysql_query($pass_query);
   //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queried)){ //no need to run loop here
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($queried);
   $user_pass = $row['password'];
   $veri_password = password_verify($password, $user_pass);
  // } //remove this too
   if($veri_password != true){$errors[] = '-Account does not exist ';}
   elseif($veri_password = true){

//CHECKING NUM ROWS
   $sql = "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
   $entered_user = mysql_query($sql);
   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($entered_user);
   //STORING ID AS SESSION
   //while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($entered_user)){//no need to run loop here
   $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($entered_user);
   //PROBLEM IS HERE
   //$row1['id'] = $id; // you can't store values in $id like this
   $id = $row1['id']; // right way to do
   } //remove this too

//ERRS ARRAY ESTABLISHED
   $errors = array();

//FURTHER VERIFYING
   if( empty($password) || empty($email) )
   {
   $errors[] = 'Please do not leave fields empty';
   }
   elseif( $num_rows != 1 )
   {
   $errors[] = '-Account does not exist ';
   }
   elseif( $num_rows == 1 )
   {
   $id = $_SESSION['key']; //again wrong you cant load $id into session
   $_SESSION['key'] = $id; //right way to load $id variable value into session

      header('Location: profile.php');
      exit();
      }
   }

   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always include

```
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);
```

As the first two lines in your code while testing, or change your test environment php.ini accordingly.
This will give you all possible help/error statements from php

Second, remove any white space before the opening Php-tag
When using session_start();
If there are spaces, as your code suggests, php will behave erratically.

Then look at your code again.
/niels ml